# Delete row if a certain field is blank --SSR

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Is there a way to remove a line in a table if a specified column is empty?

I understand I can use an "if" function to make the whole row blank. However, I want to actually remove the line, not blank it out. Is this possible?

Text1
Text2 (blank)
Text3

becomes

Text1
Text3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Hidden property on the column dynamically based on the value.

`=IIf(Fields!Text2.Value = "", True, False)`

Right-click on the column header in design mode, choose Column Visibility, click Show or hide based on an expression. Enter the expression above. Click OK, and test.

EDIT: The expression above will set the Hidden property to True if Text2 is an empty string. If you are getting back null, then this may work for you.

`=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Text2.Value), True, False)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.